# JHipster Registry / Spring Eureka Server configuration issues

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka, jhipster-registry

I don't seem to have a starter JHipster Registry instance (Spring Eureka server) configured correctly.
It keeps cycling the following messages.

```
DEBUG 7 --- [ry-scheduling-2] i.g.j.r.service.ZuulUpdaterService       : Enter: updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
DEBUG 7 --- [ry-scheduling-2] i.g.j.r.service.ZuulUpdaterService       : Exit: updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
DEBUG 7 --- [ry-scheduling-2] i.g.j.r.service.ZuulUpdaterService       : Enter: updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
DEBUG 7 --- [ry-scheduling-2] i.g.j.r.service.ZuulUpdaterService       : Exit: updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
INFO 7 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
```

Does the above indicate something amiss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, if you look at ZuulUpdaterService source, you'll see:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5_000)
public void updateZuulRoutes() {
```

So every 5 seconds, this method is run and JHipster's LoggingAspect logs its result, as it is a void method, it prints `Exit: updateZuulRoutes() with result = null`.

Feel free to adjust logging config in logback-spring.xml

Comment: Thank you. I have been facing issues for days with the cluster and am now questioning everything, your input is very helpful.